# Android - sluggish animation when using ViewAnimator, is it possible to use hardware acceleration?

Tags: android, animation, hardware-acceleration

I have the following code, that adds views to ViewAnimator

```
View step1 = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.step_1, null);
View step2 = View.inflate(activity, R.layout.step_2, null);
viewAnimator.addView(step1);
viewAnimator.addView(step2);
viewAnimator.setInAnimation(activity, R.anim.slide_in);
viewAnimator.setOutAnimation(activity, R.anim.slide_out);
```

and the following xmls

slide_in:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
            android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
            android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
            android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

slide_out:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
               android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
               android:duration="700"/>
</set>
```

Now, all works fine, however the performance of the animation looks sluggish and slow comparing to the native animations on my phone (Samsung galaxy S).

I use API level 8, can I use any hardware acceleration, or should I change my approach for the whole concept?

Thanks a bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>`
was missing from my manifest file, once added the animation is super smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Its a 2D animation only, this means it is as in Javascript in the IE7 Web Browser.

To get faster animations the only way is to do it with (OpenGL) RenderScript 
to get HW Accel through 3D when using API's < v14 (ICS).

Comment: Hardware acceleration does indeed work with 2D animations starting from Honeycomb.  However, it doesn't support all of the drawing mechanisms.  If he's targeting API level 8, it won't help at all.  He can set the target API to level 11 for Honeycomb, enable hardware acceleration, and set the minimum API level to 8.  As long as his code uses 2.2, only devices that have hardware acceleration will use it and those that don't can still use the program with possibly slightly sluggish performance.

Comment: Interesting ... can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/> was missing from my manifest file, once added the animation is super smooth, thanks for that direction!

Comment: I don't know why that would make a difference.  What I meant was this: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>`  You have to be careful with it though because Eclipse will allow you to use API 11 calls in code unless you download a plugin that prevents it.  However, if you set "HardwareAcceleration" to true in the manifest, only devices that support it will use it.  Everything will ignore it.  But hey, if that change makes everything smooth then keep it.  No need to change the manifest again.

Comment: I first tried your suggestion, then I noticed that for some reason that line was commented out, so I first tried uncommenting and voila, it worked. strange ... but I'm gonna live with that :)